# "Zuhörer*innen": How common is asterisk for gender neutrality?

Tags: gender-neutrality, neologism

From [Deutschewelle: Neue DW-Radioangebote für Afghanistan](https://www.dw.com/de/neue-dw-radioangebote-f%C3%BCr-afghanistan/a-59168216):

> Seit heute sendet die DW via Kurzwelle tägliche Radioprogramme auf Dari und Paschtu, um **Zuhörer*innen** in Afghanistan gesicherte Informationen zukommen zu lassen.

I occasionally read that newspaper for a couple of years and it was the first time I've stumbled upon such a construct.

I often hear criticism that those things mess with text-to-speech readers; Is it any different in this case? Is that formal or at least common?

Comment: It is suggested to use a form with ':' instead, as this works better. But there is a controversial discussion going on in the German-speaking world about the use of "gender-equitable language".

Comment: I'm confused.; isn't *Zuhörer* in the plural already gender neutral, meaning "listeners"?

Comment: Usually, especially in State media here in Austria it's used with "ZuhörerInnen" without any signs or asterisks. That should be, at the current time, the "official" spelling for gendering words.

Comment: @RDBury It is but the gendered language approach is trying to change the German grammar. The theory is that this will help improving gender equality. Last weekend I heard the word "BürgerInnenschaft" on the radio.

Comment: Gender-neutral language is a **very** active and controversial phenomenon, therefore the answer to "Is XXX common?" depends very much on who you ask and what year (or even what month) it is. Ask again in 2025 and perhaps there will be a vague consensus of some sort.

Comment: Besides discussing if this messing up of language, either read or spoken, is *common* one could also ask whether or not it is *helpful* for anything ;-) Just to widen one's mind.

Comment: @Roland: Thanks. So *Zuhörer* is still correct, just not the most "politically correct". Come to think of it, the DW German course *Deutsch - Warum Nicht?* always starts out with *Liebe Hörerinnen und Hörer*. *Liebe Hörer\*innen* is shorter if nothing else.

Comment: @RDBury It's the same discussion as in English. Who do you imagine when I say "police" or "teacher"? A lot of scientific studies have shown that there is an inherent bias to favor a male-only interpretation - except for jobs that are "typically female". So a "kindergarten teacher" will be imagined as female but a "school principal" is predominantly interpreted as male. The supposed "gender neutral" form is only technically neutral. In practice it's the male form but other people are "mitgemeint".

Comment: @YetCGN: it's a completely different discussion in English imo, because they have nothing comparable to the female -innen form and no grammatical gender. On the contrary, there is the discussion about the few words that do have a female variant, like actress or comedienne, where e.g. younger actresses tend to say that they want to be called actors because gender shouldn't matter.

Comment: @RDBury: It's also an abomination in the ears of many listeners, especially when the required pause Hörer - Innen is routinely skipped. All things considered, _Liebe Hörerinnen und Hörer_ is correct, liebe _HörerInnen_ is usually not, at least in spoken communication.

Comment: @Ingmar: I can well believe it. As an American, it's not really my battle to fight, so I was trying to avoid volunteering any personal opinions one way or the other as to the correctness or incorrectness of the phrase. Keep in mind that, from my point of view, German calls a tomcat 'she, a female dog 'he', and a child 'it', so all this talk about gender neutrality seems a bit confusing and out of place.

Comment: With feminism, the distinction between sex was made, the first adrressing the biological perspective, the second the social perspective. But the traditional German language was already established without such distinctions in mind - so what do you be believe does "Hörererinnen" address, biological female listeners or people who have the habit of females? And while the one side is correct:: "Hörerinnen" exclusively addresses exclusively female persons, "Hörer" doesn't exclusively male listeners. If you want to address male ones, you have to say "männliche Hörer", since there is no male suffix.

Comment: @YetiCGN: I doubt there are many scientific studies, which show, what you claim they do. Maybe people are much more used to male policemen than female ones and they therefore imagine male ones? If you hear the word "Person", do you always imagine a female person, because the grammatical gender of "Person" is female? If you imagine a policeman, does he have a mustache, does he wear glasses? Or do you construct such a picture only in the case when you get asked? And if you think of a teacher as a male person, do you think of a person with male sex or a person with a male gender role?

Comment: @userunknown I haven't heard about studies amongst English speakers, but for German speakers, there seem to exist quite a few about the German *Generisches Maskulinum*. Wikipedia has some links and a summary: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum#Studien

Comment: @userunknown There are a lot of studies in English as well, going back to at least the 1980s. I'm sure you will find them by searching for "studies on the masculine generic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asterisk, colon and underscore forms of gendering (*Zuhörer*innen, Zuhörer:innen, Zuhörer_innen*) have become popular in academia and in left-leaning social/political environments in the last 2-3 years. They're also used, albeit a bit less commonly, in public broadcasting ("öffentlich-rechtlicher Rundfunk") and public service and governmental work. Some authorities and government bodies have recently adopted internal rules about how to use gendering.

There's also a much older form of gendering with a capital I in the middle (*ZuhörerInnen*) that has been around for decades, but proponents of the newer forms see it as not including non-binary gender identities.

Particularly the newer forms have become extremely politically loaded, with conservatives often opposing them strongly, and progressives often framing them as inevitable progress towards more gender justice. Arguments of both sides can be found in the extensive and hotly contested German Wikipedia article ["Geschlechtergerechte Sprache"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache).

Comment: I would not restrict this to "left-leaning political social environments". In practice, for example, many municipal administrations and other governmental organisations on the communal, regional or national level have introduced (mandatory) usage of the asterisk to indicate gender-neutrality. This refers especially to their publications, printed materials, forms, press releases, and official letters. - Note however that the use of asterisk (or other gender-neutrality indicators) is generally limited to "official" or "business" occasions. In private communication, it is very rare.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: I agree. That's what I meant by public service, but I agree it's especially governments as well.

Comment: The fact that it is _rare in private communication_, as you correctly state, clearly indicates that this is a political topic, with acceptance in the general population very much wanting at this point. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: It is true that in private communication (which is usually congruent with informal communication) indicators of gender neutrality are rare. Still, I would not conclude from this alone that such indicators are unpopular per se. The difference is in register of speech, text genres and socio-linguistic situations where an utterance takes place. - Many users of the language who would address their friends informally by *Liebe Freunde* (thus not mentioning *Freundinnen* explicitely) would be upset to be addressed by their mayor in male-only form as *Sehr geehrte Einwohner unserer Stadt*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Umfragen haben aber gezeigt, dass der feministische Sprachbrutalismus extrem unpopulär ist und auch unter Frauen nur von einer Minderheit befürwortet wird. Es ist die Praxis einer kleinen, sich elitär verstehenden Minderheit und gerade für bildungsferne Schichten doppelt schwierig damit umzugehen - statt inklusiv zu sein ist die Sprache sehr exklusiv und damit faktisch das Gegenteil linker Politik, auch wenn sie v.a. von sich als links verkaufenden Parteien oder Gruppierungen gepflegt wird. Auch für Zuwanderer übrigens eine Zumutung.

Comment: @userunknown  I do not see "feminist language brutalism". I see, as I said above, that in certain segments of society (including official publications by governmental organisations) indicators of gender neutrality are widely in use, and that a relevant part of society is in favor of this. - What studies did you refer to?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: surveys in Germany (like Politbarometer etc.) are really quite consistent that a majority even opposes gendering in any form, even more so for the new *_: forms. Even amongst women, even amongst supporters of the Green party. Google it, you won't find a general population survey that finds a majority supporting gendering.  Regardless of how you see it, it is a project of a minority that pursues it because they think that it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Man kann freilich niemanden dazu zwingen, Kunstpausen mitten in einem Wort, wie bei Innenarchitekt:innen oder Außenarchitekt:innen als Brutalismus zu empfinden. Aber man kann sich anschauen, wie Romanautoren schreiben, wie viele von denen diesen Humbug mitmachen. Die rücksichtslosen Sprachreformer nennen ihre Innovation freilich gerne "gendersensibel", kaschierend, dass sie dies am allerwenigsten ist. Oder man denke an die Absurdität der drei Zufußgehenden, die tot im Straßengraben lagen.